# How do I vertically center numbers on an histogram plot in R?

Tags: r, plot, histogram

How do I center numbers on columns?

```
bar <- barplot(VADeaths)

text(rep(bar,each=nrow(VADeaths)),as.vector(apply(VADeaths,2,cumsum)), 
 labels=as.vector(apply(VADeaths,2,cumsum)),
 pos=1,cex=1,adj = c(0,0),col="orange",offset = 0.2)
```

This is how it looks now:

[image: 1]

And I need to make it like here:

[image: 2]

How do I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to adjust the `y` value by half of the bar height - and use `adj` to centre it...

```
bar <- barplot(VADeaths)

text(rep(bar, each=nrow(VADeaths)),
     as.vector(apply(VADeaths, 2, cumsum) - 0.5 * VADeaths),  #subtract half of bar height
     labels=as.vector(apply(VADeaths, 2, cumsum)),
     cex = 1, adj = c(0.5, 0.5), col = "orange")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

the `offset` in the text function can help you with placing the label text to the center position.
A suggestion for you, try to manipulate the `cex` so that the size of the label gets shorten according to the bar chart.

```
bar <- barplot(VADeaths)

text(rep(bar,each=nrow(VADeaths)),as.vector(apply(VADeaths,2,cumsum)), 
     labels=as.vector(apply(VADeaths,2,cumsum)),
     pos=1,cex=0.6,adj = c(0,0),col="orange",offset = 1.5)
```

Comment: I tried, but it doesnt really help, because if i increase offset, and if i try to manipulate cex, font size will be small, and even if i manipulate cex, text doesnt fit. Sorry for my english.

Comment: you can try ggplot() also